# Create a trigger that connects the class teacher and its department to the sub teacher and its department and if they dont match raise an error,

Tags: sql, oracle18c

Create a trigger before update that connects the class teacher and their department to the sub teacher and their department and if they dont have the same department raise an error

```
Teacher Table: tID, ClassteacherNo , subteacherNo (both FK of staffNo)
Staff Table: StaffNo, department
```

**Using Oracle 18c**

tried using a join but didnt know how to find the common department between the class teacher and sub

Answer (score 1):

You need no INNER JOIN, you can use :new, to get the staff number and from that you can get the department

```
CREATE TABLe staff(StaffNo int, department int,
  CONSTRAINT staff_pk PRIMARY KEY (StaffNo))
```

```
INSERT INTO staff VALUES(1,1)
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
INSERT INTO staff VALUES(2,2)
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
INSERT INTO staff VALUES(3,1)
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
INSERT INTO staff VALUES(4,1)
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
CREATE TABLE teachers (tID int , ClassteacherNo int , subteacherNo int
  , CONSTRAINT fk_ClassTeacher
    FOREIGN KEY (ClassteacherNo)
    REFERENCES staff(StaffNo)
  , CONSTRAINT fk_SubTeacher
    FOREIGN KEY (subteacherNo)
    REFERENCES staff(StaffNo))
```

```
INSERT INTO teachers VALUES(1,1,3)
```

```
1 rows affected
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER teachers_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE
   ON teachers
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   v_teacher_dep int;
   v_subteacher_dep int;
BEGIN

   -- Find department for teacher
   SELECT department INTO v_teacher_dep
   FROM staff 
  WHERE StaffNo = :new.ClassteacherNo;

   -- Find department for subteacher
   SELECT department INTO v_subteacher_dep
   FROM staff 
  WHERE StaffNo = :new.subteacherNo;


    IF v_subteacher_dep <> v_teacher_dep
      THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'The deaprtment differs between teacher and subteacher');
    END IF;
END;

/
```

```
SELECT * FROM USER_ERRORS;
```

```
UPDATE teachers SET subteacherNo = 2 WHERE tID = 1
```

```
ORA-20002: The deaprtment differs between teacher and subteacher
ORA-06512: at "FIDDLE_UUXCZJDQDWCKIGQJJFBH.TEACHERS_BEFORE_UPDATE", line 19
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'FIDDLE_UUXCZJDQDWCKIGQJJFBH.TEACHERS_BEFORE_UPDATE'
```

```
UPDATE teachers SET subteacherNo = 4 WHERE tID = 1
```

```
1 rows affected
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vPJRB0lM)